# Nested views on UI Router in MEAN Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on a MEAN application and I don't know how can I make my ui-router work as expected.

I have an index.html template where i load all my javascript and css that my application needs to work like *angular, jquery, angular-ui-x, bootstrap* and inside the index's body i have set an `ui-view`.

The first state I'm using is login, that uses all index's body `ui-view`. When users is logged in succesfully, it redirects to a home.html page (state: home) which also is using all index's body. Home has a sidebar a header and a content. Inside home's content i'm placing a nested `ui-view`.

I want every content that comes next inside home's `ui-view`. And if it's possible i want to make home abstract so i dont have to do `home.state1`, etc.

To clarify things i have draw an image (I know, my mspaint level is impressive).

[image: Problem]

And here are my states:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("login");

    $stateProvider

        .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'myApp',
                    files: [
                        'js/controllers/LoginCtrl.js',
                        'css/login.css'
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })

    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '../views/home.html',
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'myApp',
                    files: [
                        'js/controllers/homeCtrl.js',
                        'css/template.css'
                    ]
                }]);
            }]
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Since your "content" will be a nested view of "home" i don't know a way to avoid using "home.mynestedview"Why don't your want to use this syntax ?

Comment: @Okazari I was wondering if there was a way to do it without using that syntax. If there's no way i really want help doing the nested views with "home.stateX" syntax.

Comment: Working on an exemple then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exemple of multiple states with some statics parts (menus etc...)

See it working in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fos4oyKG2vY1QTeS5gRp?p=preview)

Here are the states definitions :

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
  $stateProvider
  .state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  //This is not a real view so we put it abstract
  //This will manage the menus
  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })
  .state('app.greetings', {
    url: '/greetings',
    templateUrl: 'greetings.html',
    controller: 'GreetCtrl'
  })
});
```

Hope it helped, if you have any other question feel free to ask.

EDIT : I personally prefer to call the abstract state "app" cause it symbolize the application view.

Comment: that is exact what i wanted. Thank you very much.